# Mythbuntu: Fan Art appearing behind Watch Recordings List

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I'm running Mythbuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-48-generic x86_64).  I'm not quite ready for 14.04 (ie, haven't got the half day to upgrade then iron out little quirks).

I recently did an upgrade in 12.04 (to 12.04.5) and now I'm finding that FanArt is appearing as wallpaper behind the entire screen when I select certain recordings.  Nice idea but it makes the Recordings list hard to read.  I hate it.

How do I stop this 'feature'.  Happy to just not have Fan Art so if I can simply kill the cron job that calls for it to be downloaded, that'd be fine.

Then once I stop the system downloading the Fan Art, how do I delete the Fan Art images associated with those recordings so they go away?

Comment: Sorry Mythbuntu is not supported here, please ask at http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=301

Comment: OK, thank you.  I went to Mythbuntu - "ask a question" (here: http://www.mythbuntu.org/support) and it has a link to this forum on AskUbuntu.  I guess someone here needs to tell them that... thought there's a lot of Mythbuntu threads here?!? 

For those stumbling across this... I've spent two nights trying to find an answer, then 2 mins after posting here, I found the answer:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1345355

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong but as far as I know only the core Ubuntu distros are supported here ( Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Gubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu) they probably link here for just the generic Ubuntu answers already here.

Comment: Mythbuntu is [on topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)!

Comment: @markkirby AFAIK, you are correct in that Official Ubuntu flavors are supported here, however you are incorrect in which are considered official flavors (which Mythbuntu is an official Ubuntu flavor and has been since 7.10 or 8.04) See http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/flavours

Comment: @Scootre When you say it's hard to read, is it just slightly more difficult because there is less contrast, or is it REALLY difficult to read. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @tgm4883 Thanks for the info, I will change my close vote

Comment: @markkirby I believe you.  Nonetheless, the official Mythbuntu page directs me right here from the "Ask a Question" link on the page I gave you.   Perhaps you might offer some help as to where the right forum would be to post the question, as opposed to pointing the blame finger please?

Comment: @Eric Caralho: agreed, thank you.  Doing a search on this forum shows a lot of Mythbutnu threads with very helpful answers.  It'd be good if there were even more helpful posters.

Comment: @markkirby:  This: "however you are incorrect in which are considered official flavors" - Please show me where I said that??  How did you go when you made contact with the Mythbuntu webmaster telling him the link on their official page to this forum was not correct?

Comment: @Scootre What ?  Looking back over these comments I never said you said "however you are incorrect in which are considered official flavors", the user tgm4883 said this to me about mythbuntu being an official distro, so I really don't get point of your comment here. Also you ask me to provide alternative places for you to ask about Mythbuntu ? Did you even read my comments ? There are two in the very first comment, do you keep tagging me by mistake or something ? Please clarify what the meaning of your last comment was, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solves the issue:

https://forum.mythtv.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=332

1. Edit:  /usr/share/mythtv/themes/*Your Theme Name*/recordings-ui.xml
2. Comment out the fanart section at the top relating to fanart.

You can also change the same xml file for the other themes, found in the same directory.

The poster suggests that any other upgrades will overwrite this file which explains why the upgrade I did screwed it up in the first place.

Works for me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In the frontend if you go into the theme chooser you should have the ability to choose Mythbuntu Classic, which is more in line with what you are looking for.

Comment: I've been running Mythbuntu for about 6 + years an only ever run MythCenter wide without issue.  This problem has never come up until upgrade I did, as noted above, caused this problem to start about a week ago.  Thanks for the tip about changing themes, but I'd like to go down the avenue of finding the cause first.